# Is this the correct way to handle a approval for ERC20

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, erc-20-approve

Please let me know if this is correct.

```
function handleApproval(IERC20 _token, uint256 _numTokens) public returns(bool){
_token.approve(address(this), _numTokens);
return(true);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

No, the approval for ERC20 token must be do from  user.

The user must give permission at smart contract to access his wallet and just this moment the smart contract can transfer user's tokens.
If user did not give permission accessing to his wallet then smart contract cannot transfer user's tokens.

In your function, smart contact approve itself to transfer `_numTokens`, therearefore in your smart contract this function is wrong and should be delete.
You must to only define the function where smart contract transfer user's token inside itself using `transfer` or `transferFrom` function.

If you want to test your smart contract approving function, go into [testnet] etherscan and find the token's address, go into section called `Contract` -> `Write Contract` -> `Connect to Web3` -> `Expand approve method` -> Insert your smart contract's address and the token maximum amount that this smart contract can spend from your wallet -> `Click on Write`.
When transaction has confirmed, you can finaly transfer user's token to your smart contract.